# java.lang.ClassCastException Object to HashTable.Entry

Tags: java

I'm trying to create an array with *Entry < K, V >*  elements. With this code, I've got java.lang.ClassCastException. How can I fix this?

```
public class HashTable<K, V> {
    private final int INITIAL_SIZE = 128;
    private Entry<K, V>[] table;

    public HashTable() {
        table = (Entry<K,V>[]) new Object[INITIAL_SIZE];
    }

    static class Entry<K, V> {
        // Here comes constructor and other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot create a map from an array of object.

Comment: @Nicolas I want to create an array, where I will store Entry<K,V>. Is it impossible?

Comment: Well you could do this `List<Entry<K, V>> list = new ArrayList<>()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
table = (Entry<K, V>[]) new Map.Entry[INITIAL_SIZE];
```

Comment: So right solution here is 

    table = (Entry<K, V>[]) new Entry[INITIAL_SIZE]

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can create your own Array or List of Entry Abhilekh Singh and Nicolas showed you how to do it.

But for typical use cases, java has already such a Class. It is [`java.util.Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) (that the common interface), the most often used implementation is [`java.util.HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

You can add entries to that Map with `put(key, value)` and can obtain a Set> with `entrySet`.